# Jenkins Artifactory plugin: fail-no-op option

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, artifactory

In Jenkins (both freestyle and pipeline jobs), I would like the Artifactory plugin to have the same behavior as Jfrog CLI with the `--fail-no-op` option, i.e. fail the build if no artifacts are downloaded / uploaded.

Is it possible to add this option? Maybe in the upload/download spec so that this behavior can be used both via Jfrog CLI and the Jenkins Artifactory plugin?

Comment: I'm looking to set up the same behaviour. Did you get this working?

Comment: I didn't. The way I solved it was by using JFrog CLI (or curl and JSON processing, I am not sure) and counting artifacts before downloading.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. That's the approach I was thinking if I couldn't do it the other way